# Apache commons file Upload not uploading and renaming all files

Tags: apache, servlets, file-upload, tomcat7

I have to upload 6 files to the server and rename them,but for some reasons below code seems to be working on local host and uploading everything correctly,but the same piece of code does not work on server when hosted. I just sometimes 2 files or 3 files renamed and uploaded.Can someone take a look at this code and give me some opinion.

```
 } else if (!item.isFormField()) {
                                       long size = item.getSize();
                    String contentType = item.getContentType();
                   System.out.println("Field Name = " + item.getFieldName()
                            + ", File Name = " + item.getName()
                            + ", Content type = " + item.getContentType()
                            + ", File Size = " + item.getSize()
                            + ", boolean isInMemory = " + item.isInMemory());
                    String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                    String name = item.getName();
                    if ((fieldname.equals("img1")) && name != null) {
                        if ((size < 1048576) && (("image/jpeg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/jpg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/gif".equals(contentType)) || ("image/png".equals(contentType)) || ("image/bmp".equals(contentType)))) {
                            String filetype = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
                            ImageName = System.currentTimeMillis() + filetype;
                            System.out.println(" ImageName1 is " + ImageName + "'");                           
                            businessfForm.setImg1(ImageName);
                        } else {
                            request.setAttribute("ImageError", ImageError);
                        }

                    } else if ((fieldname.equals("img2"))&& name != null){
                        if ((size < 1048576) && (("image/jpeg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/jpg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/gif".equals(contentType)) || ("image/png".equals(contentType)) || ("image/bmp".equals(contentType)))) {
                            String filetype = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
                            ImageName = System.currentTimeMillis() + filetype;
                            System.out.println(" ImageName2 is " + ImageName + "'");                           
                            businessfForm.setImg2(ImageName);
                        } else {
                            request.setAttribute("ImageError", ImageError);
                        }
                    } else if ((fieldname.equals("img3"))&& name != null) {
                        if ((size < 1048576) && (("image/jpeg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/jpg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/gif".equals(contentType)) || ("image/png".equals(contentType)) || ("image/bmp".equals(contentType)))) {
                            String filetype = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
                            ImageName = System.currentTimeMillis() + filetype;
                            System.out.println(" ImageName3 is " + ImageName + "'");                           
                            businessfForm.setImg3(ImageName);
                        } else {
                            request.setAttribute("ImageError", ImageError);
                        }
                    } else if ((fieldname.equals("img4"))&& name != null){
                        if ((size < 1048576) && (("image/jpeg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/jpg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/gif".equals(contentType)) || ("image/png".equals(contentType)) || ("image/bmp".equals(contentType)))) {
                            String filetype = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
                            ImageName = System.currentTimeMillis() + filetype;
                            System.out.println(" ImageName4 is " + ImageName + "'");                           
                            businessfForm.setImg4(ImageName);
                        } else {
                            request.setAttribute("ImageError", ImageError);
                        }
                    }  else if ((fieldname.equals("img5"))&& name != null){
                        if ((size < 1048576) && (("image/jpeg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/jpg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/gif".equals(contentType)) || ("image/png".equals(contentType)) || ("image/bmp".equals(contentType)))) {
                            String filetype = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
                            ImageName = System.currentTimeMillis() + filetype;
                            System.out.println(" ImageName5 is " + ImageName + "'");                           
                            businessfForm.setImg5(ImageName);
                        } else {
                            request.setAttribute("ImageError", ImageError);
                        }
                    } else if ((fieldname.equals("img6"))&& name != null){
                        if ((size < 1048576) && (("image/jpeg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/jpg".equals(contentType)) || ("image/gif".equals(contentType)) || ("image/png".equals(contentType)) || ("image/bmp".equals(contentType)))) {
                            String filetype = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
                            ImageName = System.currentTimeMillis() + filetype;
                            System.out.println(" ImageName6 is " + ImageName + "'");                           
                            businessfForm.setImg6(ImageName);
                        } else {
                            request.setAttribute("ImageError", ImageError);
                        }
                    }         
                    File file = new File(destinationDir, ImageName);
                   try {
                        item.write(file);                        
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(xxx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to parse upload request", ex);
                    }
                }
```

Update. Print statement output is as below,

```
Field Name = img1, File Name = 1.jpg, Content type = image/jpeg, File Size = 24236, boolean isInMemory = false
 ImageName1 is 1393377151014.jpg'
Field Name = img2, File Name = 2 (2).jpg, Content type = image/jpeg, File Size = 240476, boolean isInMemory = false
 ImageName2 is 1393377151015.jpg'
Field Name = img3, File Name = 2.jpg, Content type = image/jpeg, File Size = 27127, boolean isInMemory = false
 ImageName3 is 1393377151015.jpg'
Field Name = img4, File Name = 3 (2).jpg, Content type = image/jpeg, File Size = 295437, boolean isInMemory = false
 ImageName4 is 1393377151015.jpg'
Field Name = img5, File Name = 4 (2).jpg, Content type = image/jpeg, File Size = 248775, boolean isInMemory = false
 ImageName5 is 1393377151015.jpg'
Field Name = img6, File Name = 5.jpg, Content type = image/jpeg, File Size = 30309, boolean isInMemory = false
 ImageName6 is 1393377151015.jpg'
```

Comment: so is your println stuff outputting properly?

Comment: Yes, added the details for print.

Comment: I sugegst that you add more debugging info?  Maybe a server side problem?

Comment: Any suggestions ? I have centos linux 5.9 with tomcat 7.50 server and in localhost I have windows 7 with tomcat 7.50.Its simple form and does not do anything extra,just upload the images,renames them and then store the names to db.its iterating faster on internet than localhost.

Comment: You should provide some more details, what does it mean "it does not work on server"?
Could you provide the stacktrace?

Probably the security manager is blocking your request.
Or maybe you have just to adjust your current settings (maybe you are trying to write in a location where you have no permission)

Comment: I am uploading 6 different images,and then storing it on server.When I  use the code on local host, it uploads and renames all 6 images correctly,but when I upload the code on the server and do the same steps, I see only 2 images are uploaded(Pls see the output of print statement, you will see 4 files with same timestamp and name). I also dont see any exceptions being generated.On the server out of 6 images, I see only 2 images being uploaded.had it been permission, I should not see anything on server, I see 2 images on server than than 6.